# How to set Type.IsGenericTypeDefinition to true?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have an many class with BeginDate and EndDate properties, I want to build generic method that return one object as List of the same type but with `BeginDate=EndDate`.

Ex:

> Item.BeginDate = 2011-05-01 ,
>   Item.EndDate = 2011-05-03

the result must be

> Item1.BeginDate = 2011-05-01 ,
>   Item1.EndDate = 2011-05-01
>
> Item2.BeginDate = 2011-05-02 ,
>   Item2.EndDate = 2011-05-02
>
> Item3.BeginDate = 2011-05-03 ,
>   Item3.EndDate = 2011-05-03

I tried the following code

```
<Extension()> _
        Public Function GetRatesPerDay(Of T As Class)(ByVal oldRatesList As List(Of T)) As List(Of T)
            If oldRatesList Is Nothing OrElse oldRatesList.Count = 0 Then
                Return New List(Of T)
            End If
            Dim ratesInDays As New List(Of T)

            Dim oldBeginDate = oldRatesList.Where(Function(D) D IsNot Nothing).Min(Function(D) GetType(T).GetProperty("BeginDate", GetType(DateTime)).GetValue(D, Nothing))
            Dim oldEndDate = oldRatesList.Where(Function(D) D IsNot Nothing).Max(Function(D) GetType(T).GetProperty("EndDate", GetType(DateTime)).GetValue(D, Nothing))

            Dim currentDay As DateTime = oldBeginDate

            Dim typeArgs() As Type = {GetType(DateTime), GetType(DateTime), GetType(Nullable(Of Double)), GetType(String), GetType(HUMPSBaseClasses.RoomRateType)}
            Dim constructed As Type = GetType(T).MakeGenericType(typeArgs)

            While currentDay <= oldEndDate
                Dim dayRate = (From D In oldRatesList _
                                Where D IsNot Nothing _
                                AndAlso currentDay >= GetType(T).GetProperty("BeginDate", GetType(DateTime)).GetValue(D, Nothing) _
                                AndAlso currentDay <= GetType(T).GetProperty("EndDate", GetType(DateTime)).GetValue(D, Nothing) _
                                Select New With {.NightRate = GetType(T).GetProperty("NightRate", GetType(Nullable(Of Double))).GetValue(D, Nothing), _
                                                 .RatePlanID = GetType(T).GetProperty("RatePlanID", GetType(System.String)).GetValue(D, Nothing), _
                                                 .RoomRateType = GetType(T).GetProperty("RoomRateType", GetType(HUMPSBaseClasses.RoomRateType)).GetValue(D, Nothing) _
                                                 }).SingleOrDefault()

                If dayRate IsNot Nothing Then
                    Dim tempRate As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(constructed)
                    tempRate = New With {.BeginDate = currentDay, _
                                             .EndDate = currentDay, _
                                             .NightRate = dayRate.NightRate, _
                                             .RatePlanID = dayRate.RatePlanID, _
                                             .RoomRateType = dayRate.RoomRateType}
                    ratesInDays.Add(tempRate)
                End If
                currentDay = currentDay.AddDays(1)
            End While
            Return ratesInDays
        End Function
```

but I faced a problem that `Type.IsGenericTypeDefinition` of my classes is false.

How can I set it to true?

Comment: thanks for your replay but that not helped me :( , I made some changes on my code and faced another problem which is cannot convert anonymous type to generic type?

Comment: this fix my problem [http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/AnonymousTypeTransform.aspx](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/AnonymousTypeTransform.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. That is a read-only property.

You're getting `false` because the class isn't generic. Only your method is.

You should be able to reflect on the type and retrieve your MethodInfo. You can then use either [`MethodInfo.IsGenericMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.isgenericmethod.aspx) or [`MethodInfo.IsGenericMethodDefinition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.isgenericmethoddefinition.aspx).

Your other option would be to modify the class to be generic, but that would be overkill since this is (I'm guessing here) the only method that needs the generic parameter.

Comment: thanks for your replay but that not helped me :( , I made some changes on my code and faced another problem which is cannot convert anonymous type to generic type?

Answer (score 1):

You can't set the value of this property - it is read-only.